# How does Java interact with buttons on http webpage?

Tags: java, http, button, html

I have little knowledge about web programming, and I was looking through a lot of examples which gives alot of examples about writing on the webpage for web browser to see, but nothing about getting request when user presses a button the webpage.

For example, upon opening the server, it opens the port 80, then I want to go to web browser and type "localhost:80" to access the webpage made by the server client. The webpage has a button which when I click it, webpage changes to something else like "Clicked!".

Can someone show me an example code of this? Link to an example would be great as well.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.w3schools.com/ ?

Comment: Did you perchance mean *javascript*?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using something like Apache's [`HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to imitate a button press, which is just an *HTTP POST*. And if you don't want to use a third-party library, the standard Java library already rolls its own.